# Display data inside form input value from form output in Express js + MongoDB + PUG

Tags: javascript, forms, mongodb, express, pug

I'm trying to display the - retrieved - form input results from mongoDB in my form input value field. However, I get the error 'Cannot read property 'length of undefined'. Please see code snippets below - 'retrieve.pug' displays retrieved data correctly, but can't resubmit, 'profile.pug' throws an error, if I try to display the values inside. Any advice is highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!!

Here's the code:

profile.pug - Display form input with retrieved values -> ERROR !

```
ul
          each userinfo in userinfos
              form(action='/', method='POST')
                label(for='userinfo[firstName]') First name:
                input(type='text', name="userinfo[lastName]", value=userinfo.firstName)
                label(for='userinfo[lastName]') Last name:
                input(type='text', name="userinfo[lastName]", value=userinfo.lastName)
                label(for='userinfo[streetAddress]') Street address:
                input(type='text', name="userinfo[streetAddress]", value=userinfo.streetAddress)
                label(for='userinfo[state]') State:
                input(type='text', name="userinfo[state]", value=userinfo.state)
                label(for='userinfo[zip]') Zip:
                input(type='text', name="userinfo[zip]", value=userinfo.zip)
                label(for='userinfo[country]') Country:
                input(type='text', name="userinfo[country]", value=userinfo.country)
                label(for='userinfo[city]') city:
                input(type='text', name="userinfo[city]", value=userinfo.country)
                input(type='submit')
```

app.js - Filling in form input and retrieving it to 'retrieve.pug'=> displayed SUCCESSFULLY - HOWEVER, can't resubmit the form !

```
app.post('/retrieve', function(req, res){
  Userinfo.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.session.userId }, {$set:{ firstName:
    req.body.firstName, lastName: req.body.lastName, streetAddress: req.body.streetAddress,
    city: req.body.city, state: req.body.state, zip: req.body.zip, country: req.body.country,
    postedBy: req.session.userId}}, {upsert: true, new: true}, function(err, Userinfo){
      if(err){
          if (err) res.json(err);
      }
      res.redirect('/retrieve');
      console.log(Userinfo);
  });
});

app.get('/retrieve', function(req, res){
    Userinfo.find({ _id: req.session.userId }, function(err, docs){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else    res.render('retrieve', {userinfos: docs});
    });
});
```

Comment: you missed "retrieve" in form action, it should be like  form(action='/retrieve', method='POST')

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. The thing is, the user should submit the information and stay on the same page, after submission the information is displayed in the form input as value="userinfo.name" - however that gives me an error message - in 'profile.pug'. Any ideas?

Comment: what error message you getting ?

Comment: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - when trying to use 'profile.pug'. 'retrieve.pug' has the same code , but works fine.

Comment: can you show more code how you trying to use profile.pug?